# Which way is preferred: with(context-manger) db session + for loop

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, with-statement

`#using sqlalchemy`

```
for item in large_list_of_complex_objects:
   with postgres.PostgresSessionMaker() as session:
        ...
        device_db = session.query(SomeTable).filter(SomeTable.id == item.id).all()
        ...
```

or

```
with postgres.PostgresSessionMaker() as session:
        for item in large_list_of_complex_objects:
            ...
            device_db = session.query(SomeTable).filter(SomeTable.id == item.id).all()
            ...
```

which one is preferred in terms of pythonic / efficiency ?

Comment: I think the second option. Since it initialize session just one time. And no reason to initial session n time in side loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible optimisations here.

First of all, initialise the session *outside* the loop. Repeatedly closing and opening sessions creates unnecessary overhead in your application.

Secondly, if you can avoid it, don't execute multiple queries that are identical bar the query value in a loop. Use an `IN` clause instead.

So the most optimal query might look like:

```py
with postgres.PostgresSessionMaker() as session:
    item_ids = [obj.id for obj in large_list_of_complex_objects]
    device_dbs = session.query(SomeTable).filter(SomeTable.id.in_(item_ids)).all()
    ...
```